# Foursquare checking using API

Tags: c#, foursquare, checkin

I am trying to checkin to Foursquare using the API, I have obtained the oauth_token and am doing a POST request with the oauth_token. According to the documentation the endpoint I'm hitting is https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add. This however returns a 400 Bad Request message. This is my code in C#

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?oauth_token"+ oauth_token + "&venueId=" + venueId);

request.Method = "POST";

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

When I do the same in curl however, it posts a checkin and I get a json response back

curl --data "oauth_token=[oaut_token]&venueId=[venueId]" https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add

Comment: please obfuscate your oauth_token. even if such a token is time sensitive, it still is sensitive data which should not be made public.

Comment: Oops I meant to do that..thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately what worked is the following:

```
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            reqparm.Add("oauth_token", oauth_token);
            reqparm.Add("venueId", venueId);

            byte[] responsebytes = wc.UploadValues(URI, "POST", reqparm);
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
        }
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should write your data to request input stream: [HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx)

Comment: I tried this method, doesnt work either. Check below for what ultimately worked